# WebScraping Application

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

No errors but not having anything printed from this lot of code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
    
###This is the code to pull HTML from Jora's default search sorted by Date 

html_text = requests.get('https://au.jora.com/jobs-in-Maryborough-QLD?sp=facet&l=Maryborough+QLD&st=date').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
jobs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "jobresults")
    for job in jobs:
       #job_title = job.text.replace(' ', ' ')
        location = job.find('span', class_= 'job-location')
        if 'Maryborough' in location:
            company_name = job.find('span', class_ = 'job-company')
            print(f'''
            Company Name: {company_name}
            Location: {location}
            Job Title: {job_title}
            ''')
```

Comment: Check your query again, because this has no results: `requests.get('https://au.jora.com/jobs-in-townname?sp=facet&l=&st=date')`

Comment: if you want to see something on screen then you have to use `print()`. You could also use `print()` to see what you get in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see how code is working. And first you could use `print()` to see what you get in `html_text`. You have to remeber that modern pages use JavaScript to add items on page but `requests`/`beautifulsoupt` can't run JavaScript. And also server may send different html for different browsers and devides (phote, notebook, tablet) and this depend on header `User-Agent`

Comment: and please, always show real URL - your `jobs-in-townname` doesn't give any results but only message `The location townname could not be found.` And we live in different places on earth and we don't know if `townname` is real (or not) place in your country

Answer (score 0):

I found two problems:

**First:** if you will use `print(len(jobs))` then you should see it gets only one object. It is object with all offers inside, and later it can find only one location in this single object. You should use better `find()` to get every offer as separated object. ie.

```
jobs = soup.find('div', class_="jobresults").find_all('article')
```

or using CSS selector

```
jobs = soup.select('div.jobresults article')
```

**Second:** to compare locations you have to get `.text`

```
if 'Maryborough' in location.text:
```

You should use `.text` also with other elements to display them without HTML tags. You may also use `.strip()` to remove spaces, tabs, new lines which usually are at the end of strings in HTML. Evetually you can use `.get_text(strip=True)`

---

Full working code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://au.jora.com/jobs-in-Maryborough-QLD?sp=facet&l=Maryborough+QLD&st=date').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

jobs = soup.find('div', class_="jobresults").find_all('article')
#jobs = soup.select('div.jobresults article')  # CSS selector
print('len(jobs):', len(jobs))

for job in jobs:
    location = job.find('span', class_='job-location').text.strip()  # <-- .text
    if 'Maryborough' in location:
        company_name = job.find('span', class_='job-company').text.strip()  # PEP8: inside `()` use `=` without spaces
        job_title = job.find('h3', class_='job-title').text.strip() 
        print(f'''
Company Name: {company_name}
Location: {location}
Job Title: {job_title}
''')
```

Result:

```
Company Name: East Coast Apprenticeships
Location: Maryborough QLD
Job Title: Apprentice Plumber


Company Name: East Coast Apprenticeships
Location: Maryborough QLD
Job Title: Apprentice Landscaper


Company Name: Signature Care Operations
Location: Maryborough QLD
Job Title: Personal Carers (AINs)


Company Name: Signature Care Operations
Location: Maryborough QLD
Job Title: Enrolled Nurses
```

---

BTW: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thank you heaps, its working. I'll read the link as well lol